# How to export my webpage to pdf using javascript like what the chrome print function do

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome plugin that requires using JS to export the current page to a PDF and save it locally. The PDF needs to preserve its
style, on which the text can be selected and the link can be clicked. In fact, I want it just like the PDF file exported by the chrome printing function. However, I need to use code to automatically complete this function, Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Assuming you want to do it in an extension, use chrome.debugger API and [Page.printToPDF](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-printToPDF) method. To get more info, google up other similar extensions and documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Google Chromes [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) package. It uses headless Chrome to take screenshots, print PDF of pages and much more.

You can play around with the sandbox [here](https://puppeteersandbox.com/), select PDF in the dropwdown, enter a URL and click Run to get a sample PDF output of what the page might look like as a PDF.

Comment: Well, I need to print the screen after some kind of users' actions (for example: open a modal window) , so I think maybe the  headless Chrome screenshots cannot help. Is there any other ways to just print the current page in chrome's extends API?